# В телеграмм бот (библиотека aiogram) не добавляются новые команды в кнопке меню

Tags: python, aiogram

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделал кнопку меню, по образцу из [по образцу](https://lolz.guru/threads/3776501/)

Решил добавить потом свои команды, но они не обновляются в кнопке. Пробовал перезагрузить бота, очищал историю, менял токен... даже удалил код, который добавляет эту кнопку... В чем же дело...?))
Сам код вставил после всех команд (в конце):

```
async def set_default_commands(dp):
await dp.bot.set_my_commands(
    [
        types.BotCommand('start', 'Запустить бота'), 
        types.BotCommand("shop_centre", "БД торговых центров из 2% Перечня"), 
        types.BotCommand("FNS", "БД ФНС, пока что загружена по юр. лицам"),
    ]
)
await set_default_commands(dp)
```

Comment: А чем отец ботов не угодил для установки таких кнопок?

Comment: Надо почитать про это, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Находите папу ботов:

[image: @BotFather]

Пишите `/setcommands`, вам дают выбрать бота которому вы хотите установить команды. После выбора вас попросят написать команды формата:

```
command1 - Description
command2 - Another description
```

Рил пример(без слеша, скобок и прочего):

```
start - запустить бота
shop_centre - БД торговых центров из 2% Перечня
```

Если после, ответ выглядит так же:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения], у вас все получилось!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я честно без понятия как лучше. Но мне ближе всё же способы которые проще и менее затратны.

Comment: Спасибо большое, все получилось) действительно, век живи век учись... гораздо проще. Не мог понять, почему у меня не получается команду внести по /setcommands. оказывается из-за больших букв "FNS", поставил их маленькими "fns" и заработало.